# Opening .xlsx with VBA, File in Use error. Read-only not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to scan through a specific folder and open the most recently titled Excel file. The files are named '10 1 13' and '10 2 13' ect. My sub correctly identifies the most recent file. However, when it attempts to open it, I get the following error:

```
'Filename' is currently in use. Try again later.
```

The file will usually be in use by someone, but is only modified once a day. All I need to do is open a read-only workbook and copy data from it. No modifying or saving is required, which is why I tried the 'ReadOnly:= True' arguement, but I still get an error message.

The file path '\Hsrkdfs\hsdata\rk\grp06....' is because I am pulling from a network where everyone's network access isn't mapped the same. Some access this folder from the G: drive, others the R:, and this macro must be functional from all computers. Debug points me to the 'Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilename, ReadOnly:=True' line.

Is there a more robust way to open the Workbook? Another method to force it open regardless of use? Or a way to avoid the conflict entirely? Thank you.

```
Sub GetMostRecentFile()

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim myFolder
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim dteFile As Date

    'set path for files - CHANGE FOR YOUR APPROPRIATE FOLDER
    Const myDir As String = "\\Hsrkdfs\hsdata\rk\grp06\Rockford Repair Station Quality\DELIVERY\Daily Status report - commercial"

    'set up filesys objects
    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)   

    'loop through each file and get date last modified. If largest date then store Filename
    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
            dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            strFilename = objFile.Path
        End If
    Next objFile
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilename, ReadOnly:=True  

    Set FileSys = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: hit ctrl+alt+delete and just make sure YOU do not have an extra instance of excel hanging under `Processes` tab. It is possible that you are have the file open in another invisible instance thats why you can't reopen it. Another thing is to switch `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` when trying to open the workbook but I doubt this would help much in your case.

Comment: If you only need to extract some data from it, maybe you can use [ExecuteExcel4Macro method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195716(v=office.11).aspx)?  Or, you could maybe create a copy (`FileSys.CopyFile(strFilename, _Destination_, True)` and then kill the copy when you're done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GetObject` if you only need to read the file. Something like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = GetObject(strFilename)

'Change this line to reflect the ranges you need to copy/paste.
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

wb.Close
```

Using this *should* allow you to copy from the workbook whether it's open by another user or not (including you).

I have noticed that this approach **doesn't** work if the workbook is protected or if the sheet you're trying to copy from is protected.

Also, only use `ThisWorkbook` like I did above if the code will be in the same workbook as the sheet you want to paste to.