# How to open Locked for Editing file as Read Only?

Tags: excel, vba, readonly, locked-files

I have a macro that opens multiple files. If it comes to a file "Locked for Editing" it will give me an error saying

> FileName is currently in use. Try again later.

How can I make it open said file as read only? I tried:

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Selected_EOS_Report_File, ReadOnly:=True
```

and

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Selected_EOS_Report_File, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
```

**Update:** The first method does work. My code runs on multiple files that pass through the "Selected_EOS_Report_File" variable. At some point a file passed through that was an Excel temp file (begins the filename with "~$"). I created an if/then statement to skip over any such files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need `Notify:= True`

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> **Notify**
>   If the file cannot be opened in read/write mode, this argument is True
>   to add the file to the file notification list. Microsoft Excel will
>   open the file as read-only, poll the file notification list, and then
>   notify the user when the file becomes available. If this argument is
>   False or omitted, no notification is requested, and any attempts to
>   open an unavailable file will fail.

Comment: Hi dadler, thanks for your help. I added that on to become `Workbooks.Open FileName:=Selected_EOS_Report_File, ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=True` and also tried `Workbooks.Open FileName:=Selected_EOS_Report_File, Notify:=True` but it gave me the same error.

Comment: If you only need to read from the files you can use `GetObject` instead of actually opening the file. What error message are you getting?

Comment: It has to read and copy information from the files to another spreadsheet in Excel. And "Run Time Error 1004. Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'FileName'. There are several possible reasons: -The file name or path does not exist. -The file is being used by another program. -The workbook you are trying to save has the same name"

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for a similar Problem I had. This will set the ReadOnly and IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended parameters.

I tested this for Excel 365.

ReadOnly: True to open the workbook in read-only mode.

IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: True to have Microsoft Excel not display the read-only recommended message (if the workbook was saved with the Read-Only Recommended option).

```
dim wbReadOnly as Workbook
Set wbReadOnly = Workbooks.Open(strXLSFileName, , True, , , , True)
```

[link to VBA Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: The OP's code already does this, in the second code snippet they provided.

Answer (score -1):

Try this?

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = GetObject(Selected_EOS_Report_File)

wb.Open 'ReadOnly:=True (removed the readonly part)
```

Derived from this post:  [Opening .xlsx with VBA, File in Use error. Read-only not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121192/opening-xlsx-with-vba-file-in-use-error-read-only-not-working)

**edit**

A post here indicates a similar issue for older versions, and that if you undate to xlsx then it goes away:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c9f7444-a2c7-4598-beca-21a6d5575d94/excel-file-currently-in-use

Comment: Hello n8, thanks for your help. I gave that a go, but got the error "Run Time Error 438. Obeject doesnt support this property or method." and it highlights the "wb.Open ReadOnly:=True" line when I debug

Comment: Unfortunately, same error when the ReadOnly bit is commented out.

Comment: Yeah I see that `.Open` isn't a method for workbook (weirdly, since `.Close` is).  What file extension are you working with, xls or xlsx?

Comment: Hey n8! Thanks again for your help. I think I kinda figured out what was going on. The original method I posted was working. What wasnt though, was that the file it was actually trying to access was a temp file (one that begins with "~$") which my code couldnt read (as it is not an Excel file.) I wrote in an if then statement to deal with this, and basically skip over any temp files, only running files that have been saved.

Comment: It's always something